# How to sort only some rows of a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting

I have a following table:

And I want to sort the rows with names and ages with their articles -> My JavaScript code for sorting looks like this:

Right now it sorts the names and articles weirdly together.
My idea was somehow connect the nested rows to the original row so it will sort (move) with its original row but I'm unsure how to do it.
How can I approach it?

```js
const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;
const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) =>
  v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2)
)(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));
document.querySelectorAll('.th-sortable').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', (() => {
  const tbody = document.getElementsByClassName('js-sortable-table').item(0);
  Array.from(tbody.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n)'))
    .sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
    .forEach(tr => tbody.appendChild(tr));
})));
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="th-sortable" scope="col">Name</th>
      <th class="th-sortable" scope="col">Surname</th>
      <th class="th-sortable" scope="col">Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="js-sortable-table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        John
      </td>
      <td>
        Carter
      </td>
      <td>
        44
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="nested">
      <th>
        Article
      </th>
      <th>
        Topic
      </th>
      <th>
        Date
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nested">
      <td>
        4
      </td>
      <td>
        Music
      </td>
      <td>
        12.06.2019
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nested">
      <td>
        7
      </td>
      <td>
        Free-time Activity
      </td>
      <td>
        12.08.2019
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nested">
      <td>
        8
      </td>
      <td>
        Hobby
      </td>
      <td>
        12.09.2019
      </td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td>
        Nicole
      </td>
      <td>
        Odipie
      </td>
      <td>
        21
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="nested">
      <th>
        Article
      </th>
      <th>
        Topic
      </th>
      <th>
        Date
      </th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="nested">
      <td>
        11
      </td>
      <td>
        Fashion
      </td>
      <td>
        12.09.2019
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post a simple jsfiddle so that we can play around :)

Comment: @ssBarBee They can embed the code right here...

Comment: @ssBarBee Here is a jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qrcj1oey/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a complete solution but should work with some modification.

1. nest tables inside your main table for the articles
2. use this function from w3 to sort your tables
3. I would add the last name as a class to each nested table for a given person
4. sort the main table then embed the nested table for each person (sort the nested table if you need to before you embed)

UPDATE:
1) when you get the main table eliminate the nested tables 
2) get each nested table
3) add the nested tables back in to the main table after it's been sorted

If you want more help you need to put something together and develop  a step by step game plan.  It will be easy to get specific help on a specific step.  The more you break down the steps the easier and faster it will be to get help.

This really isn't that hard (maybe tedious) but just involves some basic JS operations.

```js
function sortTable() {
  var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  switching = true;
  /*Make a loop that will continue until
  no switching has been done:*/
  while (switching) {
    //start by saying: no switching is done:
    switching = false;
    rows = table.rows;
    /*Loop through all table rows (except the
    first, which contains table headers):*/
    for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {
      //start by saying there should be no switching:
      shouldSwitch = false;
      /*Get the two elements you want to compare,
      one from current row and one from the next:*/
      x = rows[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
      y = rows[i + 1].getElementsByTagName("TD")[0];
      //check if the two rows should switch place:
      if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
        //if so, mark as a switch and break the loop:
        shouldSwitch = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (shouldSwitch) {
      /*If a switch has been marked, make the switch
      and mark that a switch has been done:*/
      rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
      switching = true;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="th-sortable" scope="col">Name</th>
      <th class="th-sortable" scope="col">Surname</th>
      <th class="th-sortable" scope="col">Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="js-sortable-table">
    <tr>
      <td>
        John
      </td>
      <td>
        Carter
      </td>
      <td>
        44
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="nested">
      <th>
        Article
      </th>
      <th>
        Topic
      </th>
      <th>
        Date
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nested">
      <td>
        4
      </td>
      <td>
        Music
      </td>
      <td>
        12.06.2019
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nested">
      <td>
        7
      </td>
      <td>
        Free-time Activity
      </td>
      <td>
        12.08.2019
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="nested">
      <td>
        8
      </td>
      <td>
        Hobby
      </td>
      <td>
        12.09.2019
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        Nicole
      </td>
      <td>
        Odipie
      </td>
      <td>
        21
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="nested">
      <th>
        Article
      </th>
      <th>
        Topic
      </th>
      <th>
        Date
      </th>
    </tr>

    <tr class="nested">
      <td>
        11
      </td>
      <td>
        Fashion
      </td>
      <td>
        12.09.2019
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: So the problem is I already have the nested tables rendered and i need to use it as a onclick sort function.This tries to sort all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use this after table load from success i use this for my dynamic table

This Working in Rise CRM for Drag tr tag using Sortable js

```
    $.ajax({
        url: base_url + "your_controller/your_function",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { id: id },
        success: function (result) {
            appLoader.hide();
            if (result.status == 1) {
                $("#template_table").html(result.content);

                // Sorting the tr tag
                var templateOptions = {
                    animation: 150,
                    chosenClass: "sortable-chosen",
                    ghostClass: "sortable-ghost",
                    onAdd: function (e) {
                        console.log('add', e);
                    },
                    onUpdate: function (e) {
                        // here load what you want to update after sorting
                    }
                };

                new Sortable(document.getElementById("template_table_body"), templateOptions);
            }
            $('div').removeClass('modal-backdrop');
        }
    });
```